# Visual bug on "An edit has been made for this post" if the user had voted on the post before

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ajax

I have searched for a while but I can't find anything really close to this.

I was reviewing edit proposal on SharePoint when I came to this answer and the related edit by Devin: [link here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/165063/5173). Since as you see the edit is strange because it improves the code snippet by making it more close to the sample in the question, I wanted to check the question to ensure that I should approve the edit.

I opened the question in a **different tab**, read it, checked the answer again and voted it. At this point I returned to the review tab and approved the edit.
A little after, I returned to the still open Question tab, to see that - as expected - the answer now had the "an edit has been made..." message alert over it. I clicked on the alert and the new answer reloaded, with no indication that I had voted it: **the numbers where correct, but the arrow wasn't lit.**

Thinking I forgot to vote, I clicked the up arrow again. The vote counter increased by one for a split second, then it returned to the original value. This time, the arrow was lit as expected.

As you can see, this doesn't seem a really dangerous bug, but I am still writing this notice for the staff to know. Free to close it as deferred, I am only interested in reporting it, a fix may not be a priority for now.

Comment: Well, the bug is in the AJAX that either fails to bring back the "current vote status" from the server, or fails to handle that detail.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, and it is not like it is a big problem either. I just wanted to have it recorded. And if I get the fabled "amazing grace" hat in the meantime, it is just an added bonus.

Comment: Cheers @SPA, just wanted to explain the tag I added actually. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't even noticed the tag. I just assumed it was my spelling. It always is the spelling.

Comment: Actually your spelling here is perfect. Kudos!